# PDO SQL select from_user = user1 to_user = user2 also vice versa like from_user = user2 to_user = user1?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have to following code:
it selects messages from user in database and shows user message and picture based on what user logged user is chatting, if message is from logged user then he will have his image on left of the page if message is from the user he is chatting he will have the image on the right of the page

```
<?php
     //$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from_user = :from_user AND to_user = :to_user ORDER BY time ASC";
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (from_user = :from_user AND to_user = :to_user) OR 
      (from_user = :touser   AND to_user = :fromuser) ORDER BY time ASC";
        $stm = $conexao_pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stm->bindParam(':to_user', $user_logged);
        $stm->bindParam(':from_user', $db_user);
        $stm->bindParam(':touser', $db_user);
        $stm->bindParam(':fromuser', $user_logged);
        $stm->execute();
        $messages_count = $stm->rowCount();
        if ($messages_count <= 0 ){
            $message_from_user = "";
            $message_to_user =  "";
            $message_content =   "";
            $message_time =  "";
            $message_read =  "";
            echo "you don't have messages";
        } else {
        }
        while($values = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            //echo $values['db_column'];
            $message_from_user = $values['from_user'];
            $message_to_user = $values['to_user'];
            $message_content =  $values['content'];
            $message_time = $values['time'];    
            $message_read = $values['message_read'];
            //echo while
            if($message_from_user == $db_user){
            echo ' <div class="container-fluid text-left" style="padding-left: 18px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <a href="user.php?user='.$message_from_user.'"><img class="rounded-circle" width="45" src="'.get_user_picture($message_from_user).'">&nbsp; @'.$message_from_user.'</a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
     '.$message_content.'
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm text-muted text-right">
      '.relativeTime( $message_time).'
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>';
            } else if($message_from_user == $user_logged){
                echo '<div class="container-fluid text-right" style="padding-right: 18px;">
 </br>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm text-muted text-left">
      '.relativeTime( $message_time).'
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
     '.$message_content.'
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
   <a href="#">@'.$message_from_user.'&nbsp;<img class="rounded-circle" width="45" src="'.$message_from_user.'"></a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

    </div>
    <hr>';

            }
        } 
        ?>
```

How to select from database in the same statement   WHERE `from_user = user1` AND `to_user = user2` also vice versa like `from_user = user2` AND `to_user = user1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add another test to the `where` conditions in your query.

```
WHERE (from_user = :from_user AND to_user = :to_user) OR 
      (from_user = :to_user   AND to_user = :from_user)
```

Comment: should I change the pdo `bindparam` ?because it's returning blank to me, I don't know, or something in my while vars are not getting let me upload my while loop

Comment: If you want to you can use another set of names to bind the 2nd set of conditions if you're more comfortable.

Comment: Test the query directly in MySQL from the command line to make sure it is working and returning what you are expecting. You will have to use hard coded values for testing but you'll know for sure if the query is working as you expect it to.

Comment: Yeah it's working as I expect but not inside with my while loop

Comment: That's a different problem entirely :) Use `print_r($values);` in your `while` loop to see what's really there.

Comment: I have the following `if ($messages_count <= 0 ){ echo "you don't have messages"}` this is what is returning to me but message it's  saved on database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197360/discussion-between-dave-and-developer).

Comment: Like I said, run the query directly in MySQL from the command line and make sure it is returning the results you think it is or should.

Comment: its working directly in MySQL  but something in my php code it's not working I can only read user1 message in the while variable `$message_from_user` only echo user1 `$message_from_user` should also get user2 in the var

Comment: Did it work as expected before modifying the `WHERE` statement?

Comment: [Edit] your question and modify what is there. We should continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197360/discussion-between-dave-and-developer).